# Getting ReportNG to generate its output in Maven's "site"?

Tags: maven, testng, surefire, reportng

I'm trying to use ReportNG with Maven (and Maven Surefire) to generate reports for the results of TestNG tests, within Eclipse.  I believe I have followed the instructions here:

http://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/better-looking-html-test-reports-for-testng-with-reportng-maven-guide/

When I run a Maven "site:site", and then look at the generated website, I see the normal TestNG report rather than the ReportNG report.

Poking around the file system, I see that ReportNG has actually created a report, in target/surefire-reports/html.  But in target/site, there's a "surefire-report.html" which is the regular TestNG report.

I am guessing that to get the ReportNG report to show up on the generated site, it would have to put an HTML page in target/site, like the regular TestNG report is.  How can I make it that happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TestNG comes with a few pre-made Report generator classes.  You can copy one, put it in your project, add a listener to trigger it, and then modify it to format your result output any way you want.